# Exception while using SelectDirectoryDialog (TSelectDirectoryDialog) in Free Pascal / Lazarus

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

I just wanted to test the "SelectDirectoryDialog" as described on the resource page: [`TSelectDirectoryDialog`](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/TSelectDirectoryDialog), the linked [doc page](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/dialogs/tselectdirectorydialog.html) is currently down. But I'm getting an exception "External:SIGSEGV". Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I put the "SelectDirectoryDialog" on the form and created a button that executes the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if SelectDirectoryDialog1.Execute then ShowMessage(SelectDirectoryDialog1.FileName);
  end;
```

I looked up a few examples ([here](https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=13428.0), [here](https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=14850.0) and [here](https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=29540.0)), but I can't find anything that's wrong with my code. I tried the [`TOpenDialog`](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/TOpenDialog), that one works without a problem.

Any ideas how to fix this? Is there a different dialogue that let's me select a directory as a quick fix?

**Update:**
The problem seems to be with the debugger, here's a [thread](https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=4832.0) describing it. Executing the Exe-File works fine. Does anyone know if the more current Version have a fix to this? (I'm using Lazarus V1.6 from 2016, FPC-V. 3.0.0, SVN-Revision 51630 - the 64bit Version).

Comment: What is SelectDirectoryDialog1's `InitialDir` set to?

Comment: @MartynA: I didn't set it explicitly, do I have to?

Comment: I don't think so, I was just wondering if it was set to some blatantly invalid value.

Comment: @MartynA Since the resource page I linked to doesn't provide any more information, is the an overview with explanations about the methods and attributes of TSelectDirectoryDialog?

Comment: Try googling for SelectDirectoryDialog documentation.  In the Lazarus IDE, going to `View | Debug Windows | Call stack` should tell you exactly where the exception is occurring.

Comment: @MartynA I tired my recourse page was the only relevant thing that came up. By the way I found my problems source: see question's update.

Comment: Well if you carry out the steps suggested by Leledumbo in the thread you linked and still get the problem, I suggest you delete this q and post a new one.

Comment: I'll do just want to wait a bit, before going through the whole update procedure, maybe someone is familiar with the problem.

Comment: Hmmm... the doc page for TSelectDirectoryDialog currently shows a 403 error.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis same thing for any other doc page I tried

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it the problem, but did you try menu -> Tools -> Options -> Debugger -> check the checkbox for DisableLoadSymbolsForLibraries ?

Comment: No, how did you come to the conclusion that this should help? Please add a link or an explanation of the context in which you used it.